# HerokuにRubyのデータをデプロイ後、画像が見れない状態です。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rubyのデータをcloud9からHerokuにデプロイ後、 rootの設定をしてデータの表示ができたのですが画像とjsがきいてなかったので

http://www.workabroad.jp/posts/1164
http://wolfmasa.hatenadiary.com/entry/2015/08/13/010347

上記の記事等を参考にconfig/production.rbに
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
を追加してjsの動きは表示できるようになったのですが、画像は見れないままでした。
他に必要な作業があるのでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/37666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決出来ました！ qiita.com/tomomomo1217/items/fa8dfa094cc4c0e4e350 を参考にdevelopment.rbにconfig.serve_static_assets = trueを追加後、 rails.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2013/03/03/125801 も参考にプリコンパイル作業が必要ということなので$ rake assets:precompile のコマンドを打ってプリコンパイル後、 qiita.com/wadako111/items/03bc00d914e62243a511 を参考に プリコンパイル後、画像ファイル名が変更されてしまっているので変更後の画像名にhtmlタグ等を書きかえてgithubとhe‌​rokuに上げ直したら表示されました。